# Exercício de condicionais

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estou com problemas nesse seguinte exércicio:

Defina a função podeSubir, recebendo 3 parâmetros: alturaPessoa (numero), vemComCompania (booleano), temProblemaCardiaco (booleano). Levar em conta as condições necessárias mencionadas abaixo:

- Atingir a altura mínima de 1,5 m (ou 1,2 m, se acompanhada por um adulto)
- Não ter qualquer problema cardíaco.

**O código ficou assim**

```js
function podeSubir(alturaPessoa, vemComCompania, temProblemaCardiaco) {
  return (
    (alturaPessoa <= 1.2 && vemComCompania) ||
    (alturaPessoa >= 1.5 && !vemComCompania) && !temProblemaCardiaco
  );
}


console.log(podeSubir(1.5, false, false))
console.log(podeSubir(1.7, false, true))
console.log(podeSubir(1.2, true, false))
console.log(podeSubir(1.2, false, false))
console.log(podeSubir(1.1, true, false))
```

Mas o problema é que não consigo passar pela última das validações:

- uma pessoa que mede 1.5m, não está acompanhada por um adulto e não tem problemas cardíacos pode subir na atração -> **correta**
- uma pessoa que mede 1.7m, não está acompanhada por um adulto e tem problemas cardíacos não pode subir na atração -> **correta**
- uma pessoa que mede 1.2m, está acompanhada por um adulto e não tem problemas cardíacos pode subir na atração -> **correta**
- uma pessoa que mede 1.2m, não está acompanhada por um adulto e não tem problemas cardíacos não pode subir na atração -> **correta**
- uma pessoa que mede 1.1m, está acompanhada por um adulto e não tem problemas cardíacos não pode subir na atração -> **está retornando true e o correto é false**

Muito obrigado pela atenção e ajuda de todos

Comment: Eu editei melhor a minha dúvida, espero que tenha ficado mais coerente e desculpa por qualquer confusão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz sentido, já que a comparação que você está fazendo é <=1.2 (menor ou igual a 1.2) e 1.1 entra nessa condição, é só mudar para >= 1.2 suponho

Comment: Muito obrigado, Adiel. O erro era exatamente esse e acabou passando despercebido por mim. Obrigado de novo por entender a minha dúvida, que no começo ficou redigida de forma confusa

Comment: Poderia aceitar minha resposta como melhor resposta então? Agradeço

Comment: Pronto, já fiz conforme pedido. Ainda estou me acostumando com a plataforma e agradeço pela paciência que teve comigo